# Section title moving to wrong page

Tags: graphics, sectioning, formatting, plot

I have a problem with the title of a section moving up to a wrong page. In my document I have a few pages that have got only pictures and no texts except the captions and the section titles. Some of these images are so big as to fit in the whole page. The second section's title goes up to the first page which is irrelevant to it. I guess it is happening because there's space on the first page to fit the title, so its going up. But I don't want that.

I'm talking about D.2 Schematic and PCB Layout

How do I fix this? I don't want to start on a new page, just let it flow naturally.[image]

It should appear between the pictures on this page:-

[image]

Comment: 1) try to set the `h!` option of the figure environment. `\begin{figure}[h!]`; 2) Try the `H` option of the `float` package; 3) Do not use the `figure` environment and manually place the figures wherever you prefer (for the captions you can use `\captionof` provided by the `caption` package). The first two solutions are generally not advisable for several reasons, but in some cases they can be useful

Comment: @Ivan Thanks for your suggestion. I tried the [!h] and [h!] both, but the figures are in the right position, it is the section title that is wrongly placed. What could I do about that? (i.e, the D.2 title)

Comment: Why not put `\clearpage` before the second section's title? This will output all previous floats before the title (which will start on a new page).

Comment: @PeterWilson Putting a \clearpage puts the lower picture of my 2nd page in a fresh page, but I want the 2 images to be on the same page as shown, just the title not to go up (just because it found space up there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having a MWE that reproduces the problem, it is difficult to give a detailed solution. In general, when you want to force the positioning of the figures, you should not use the `figure` environment. This is not a good practice but in some cases it is necessary to do it. The following MWE tries to reproduce your problem and provides a solution by doing without the `figure` environment. Clearly the page fill leaves a lot to be desired.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\newenvironment{myfig}{\medskip\begin{center}}{\end{center}\medskip}

\begin{document}

\appendix
\chapter{Schematics and layouts}

\section{Title}

\begin{myfig}
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{The caption}
\end{myfig}
\clearpage

\begin{myfig}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-b}
\captionof{figure}{The caption}
\end{myfig}

\section{Title}

\begin{myfig}
\includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-c}
\captionof{figure}{The caption}
\end{myfig}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked!